# Not executing source

Tags: r

`source()` function executes R commands which is written inside the script. Is there any way to load the script from different file location but not execute it.  Alternative to `source("getdata.R")` for just loading the file.

Comment: Use something like Rstudio and just load the script in the script editor?

Comment: Programmatically my friend

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "load" the script. Just print the contents to the console?

Answer (score 1):

It's litte awkward to do it and I am not sure if this is the way you wanted it but in any case, here is one way to do it. Use `readLines` to read the entire script. then save it as an obj with paste0 like below. You may want to execute it later. So for that you can use NSE functions  like `eval` and `parse` to execute it.

```
dt <- readLines('E:\\script.R')
obj <- paste0(dt, collapse = '\n')
eval(parse(text = obj), envir=.GlobalEnv)


# contents of script.R
#script.R
x <- 20
y <- 30
print(x + y)
print('objects are printed')
```

An alternate way could be this also, wrapping the source call inside a function, whenever you want to execute it then call the function instead.

```
func_source <- function(file='E:\\script.R'){
    source(file)
}

## call the function 

func_source()
```